# I don't get a JSON response while using PHP curl

Tags: php

I am trying to call the GitHubAPI but when I do curl_exec() the response is a simple string. I would like to get a JSON response. My code is as follows:

```php
if(isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        global $CLIENTID, $CLIENTSECRET;
        $CODE = $_GET['code'];

        $postfields = array('client_id' => $CLIENTID, 'client_secret' => $CLIENTSECRET, 'code' => $CODE);
        $json_fields = json_encode($postfields);

        $ch = curl_init("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type"=>"x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept"=>"application/json"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

        $gitResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        if($gitResponse)
        {
            echo var_dump($gitResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id='.$CLIENTID.'" title="Login with Github">
        LOGIN
        </a>';
    }
```

I've tried with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER but it didn't work so I commented it.
What I receive is good but it is a string instead of a JSON respone so I can't use the fields of the response.

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, JSON **is** a string format. You can use `json_decode()` to turn it into an array or `stdclass`

Comment: What is the content of the string?

Comment: Also, if you're going to post a JSON request body, you should set `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: access_token=22221e9d061d2bd33633d09db6aaf7f9401e0b44&scope=user%3Aemail&token_type=bearer This is one example of the string, but if I use json_decode() on it then it becomes null.

Comment: Could possibly be an issue with your request content-type. Perhaps if you request with JSON it will respond with JSON. Otherwise, that's an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded string. To decode it, you can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: Add this to your code: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));` this will ask the server to return JSON

Comment: Thank you @catcon, this solved it.

Comment: @Daniel: no worries mate

Comment: @catcon Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar: sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
```

This will request the server to return a JSON string, then you can turn that to an array to use:

```
if($gitResponse)
{
     $result = json_decode($gitResponse,true);
}
```